# Extracting random effects from a two-level logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I am running a two-level logistic model using glmer from lme4 in R.

I would like to extract the random effect terms of such a model (random effect estimate as a probability per cluster) and the standard error of this effect per cluster.

Is it possible to do so (i.e. does it make sense?) and how would one go about doing that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check the ranef() function

Comment: Thank you for your response, in the case of a binominal model, the random effects obtained through ranef() would be conditional modes, correct? How exactly are these interpreted and are both the modes and errors in log format? Thanks again!

Comment: I would think so, that's what one of my professors said about lme4, I don't actually know. I wouldn't interpret them in insolation. I might interpret them relative to each other. I might condition on specific values of the fixed effects, say, if all predictors at zero or a no predictor model, I'd simply add ranef values to the intercept then use an inverse logit transformation to obtain the cluster level predicted probabilities. About standard errors for each of them, uncertainty quantification is easier in a Bayesian setting with something like RStan. Other than that, I don't know.

Comment: One small comment: technically, I wouldn't refer to the uncertainty on the conditional mode as a "standard error", because the conditional mode isn't an estimated parameter. I'd call it the "conditional standard deviation", i.e. the standard deviation of the estimated distribution of the random effect conditional on the observed data and the fitted model.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to extract the random effect terms of such a model (random effect estimate as a probability per cluster)

As user162986 mentions than use `ranef`. As the `help("ranef")`'s title states the function

> Extract the modes of the random effects

which answer the questions

> ... the random effects obtained through `ranef()` would be conditional modes, correct?

by yes. As for the question

> I would like to extract ... the standard error of this effect per cluster.

then see the `condVar` argument of `ranef`.

As for

> How exactly are these interpreted and are both the modes and errors in log format?

then the random effect estimates are on the link scale. So that would be log-odds if you use the logistic link function. You can use the `transf` argument to the random effect estimates on odds-scale but going to probabilities will be complicated as far as I gather. Lastly, looking at the code in `getS3method("dotplot", "ranef.mer")` then it just makes a normal approximation around the mode as a mean. I can see that this is justified in the linear mixed model but I am not sure whether it is in a GLMM.

Comment: Not sure what your last sentence is referring to?  Yes, the assumption is that the conditional distribution of the random effects is normal.

Comment: I gathered that. The man page for `ranef` though reads:" _For linear mixed models the conditional modes of the random effects are also the conditional means_" which may imply that this is not the case for GLMMs.